# How would I pytest a flask wtforms custom validator?

Tags: python, flask, pytest, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I tried the code below.

But the problem is I am getting an error when I run the code. Do I have the right arguments in `make_password_contain_capital`?

Here is the custom validator.

auth/functions.py

```
def make_password_contain_capital(form, field):
    '''
    This works if the password contains a capital Char 
    and raises an ValidationError if it does not.
    This runs in the class RegistrationForm in passwordfield + confirmpasswordfield column
    ''' 
    password_form = field.data   
    word = password_form
    # any returns True when any value of char is True
    # loops through each word into a char and if any char is an uppercase return True else return False
    letter = [char for char in word if char.isupper()]
    # if the string returns a value then the string has an capital  
    if letter: 
        flash("Success password does contain a capital")
        return None    
    # else executes if "letter" is an empyty string
    else: 
        raise ValidationError("Please include a capital letter in the password field"
```

tests/non_db_functions/login_routes.py

```
from app.auth.functions import make_password_contain_capital
from wsgi import app

from app.auth.forms import LoginForm
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError

@pytest.fixture
def plaintext_password_contains_capital_form():
    password_form ='Aejfpwo;fkjeo;'
    return password_form


def test_password(plaintext_password_contains_capital_form)

    with app.test_request_context():
        form = LoginForm()
        field = plaintext_password_contains_capital_form
        with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
            make_password_contain_capital(form, field)
```

The error I am getting is below.

```
plaintext_password_contains_capital_form = 'Aejfpwo;fkjeo;'


    def test_password(plaintext_password_contains_capital_form ):

        with app.test_request_context():
            form = LoginForm()
            field = plaintext_password_contains_capital_form 
            with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
>               make_password_contain_capital(form, field)

app\tests\non_db_functions\login_routes.py:68:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  

form = <app.auth.forms.LoginForm object at 0x000002045E5EC5E0>, field = 'Aejfpwo;fkjeo;'

    def make_password_contain_capital(form, field):
        '''
        This works if the password contains a capital Char
        and raises an ValidationError if it does not.
        This runs in the class RegistrationForm in passwordfield + confirmpasswordfield column
        '''
>       password_form = field.data
E       AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'

app\auth\functions.py:16: AttributeError
============================================================ short test summary info ============================================================= 
FAILED app/tests/non_db_functions/login_routes.py::test_password - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'
```

How do I fix this?

I am importing app from wsgi.py and I have an individual PytestConfig class that is why so I run   `>>$env:FLASK_ENV="pytest" >>pytest -q --capture=no`     . Though there are other ways to do this

Thanks you to anyone who responds.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking

```
make_password_contain_capital(form, field)
```

with `field` containing `plaintext_password_contains_capital_form` (a `str`).

Then you try to access `data` on it which does not exist.

You can create a mock for it

```
...
field = MagicMock(name="field")
field.data = plaintext_password_contains_capital_form
...
```

Comment: When I add `field = MagicMock(name="field") ` the output is `<MagicMock name='field' id='1485373459568'>`. How do I access 'name=field'?

Also I am really confused by using the line `field.data = plaintext_password_contains_capital_form`. Can you explain?


@Diego Torres Milano

Comment: your `password_form = field.data` expects that

Comment: Okay let me rephrase this.  Whenever I use 

`with pytest.raises(ValidationError): 
    make_password_contain_capital(form, field)
`   
I get the error https://pastebin.com/y4Aj1BfE.



This happens if I make `field = MagicMock(name="field")` or even if I change `field = MagicMock(name="Field")` . This also happens if I make `form =Login_Form()` or even if  I change `form='Random string'`  . I have tried all 4 combos and still get the error above. Why is this? I ran the code outside of pytest in the development and I am still getting the error.

@Diego Torres Milano